# Magento2: How to move from localhost wamp to live server

Tags: magento2, migration

I'm trying to move local magento2 instance to live server. I've moved all the files and database. Changed entries in core_config_data for base_url. 
Also, removed var/cache, var/view_processed directories. Set proper permissions for var/ folders. But still I'm getting next error and also the no magento2 commands working on SSH.

> Fatal error: Cannot instantiate interface
>   Magento\Store\Api\StoreRepositoryInterface in
>   /data/sites/web/hypebe/subsites/deboomhut.hype.be/deboomhut-webshop/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php
>   on line 73

Any help would be appreciable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you removed everything from var/generation/*, var/di/*? You might also need to run ```composer install``` again to regenerate the classmapping.

Comment: what i did is installed fresh magento via composer and used old database. Trying to setup now. All shell commands are working now.